# Hosted Network Not Supported

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

Back when I had Windows 8, I would run Hosted Networks from my computer all the time using the `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` code in the command line terminal. However, since I have updated to Windows 10, I have been unable to start a hosted network. I have looked all over for an answer and there is nothing.

When I type `netsh wlan show drivers` the command line comes up with

```
Hosted Network Supported : No
```

but, it use to work, it use to be supported. In my research for trying to find out why this is, I have found many tutorials on saying to Enable the "Virtual Network Adapter" within the Device Manager with Hidden Devices shown, however that device does not appear. I have tried to scour the internet in search of the Virtual Network Adapter driver and it is MIA. To add, when I type `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` in the command line, this pops up:

```
Status : Not available
```

and when I type `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` this error pops up:

```
The hosted network could not be started. 
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

How do I get my hostednetwork to be able to start and fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried `enable the "Virtual Network Adapter" within the Device Manager with Hidden Devices shown` I assume you also tried `netsh wlan set hostednetwork [mode=]allow` first.

If none of that worked, there is a possiblity that the driver for the Wi-Fi adapter does not implement the required protocols. From [About the Wireless Hosted Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243.aspx):

> This feature requires that a Hosted Network capable wireless adapter is installed in the local computer. The driver for the wireless adapter must implement the wireless LAN device driver model defined by Microsoft for use on Windows 7. To receive the Windows 7 logo, a wireless driver must implement the wireless Hosted Network feature.

Though, the above implies that a *signed* driver is supposed to support Virtual Wi-Fi's.

Comment: Yes, I do believe my issue is that I do not have the correct drivers to support Virtual Wi-Fi's although I use to. How would I get such a driver onto my device. I have looked all over and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is long due without any accepted answer. So, I'm writing this because I experienced the same few days ago.

First, I tried to check whether my network adapter supports hosted network using this.

```
netsh wlan show driver | findstr Hosted
```

It showed "No", so tried updating the drivers. Still the result was same. Then tried the "[No WIFI](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NK0DST7HZX5)" app from Microsoft store as explained in [How to setup a hotspot in Windows 10](https://devreads.xyz/hosted-network-supported-no-how-to-setup-a-hotspot-in-windows-10/) article and it worked!!!.

Other option was upgrading my network adapter to a hosted network supported one which I didn't want because above method was sufficient.