# Is it possible to create a wireless connection between a Windows laptop and an Android smartphone when hostednetwork is not supported?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, android

On my previous laptop, I used `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` to create a WiFi network (that worked even if the laptop is not connected to Internet), connected my Android smartphone to it and did some nice stuff by connecting to my web server on Android (less frequently vise versa).

My current laptop doesn't support hostednetwork (pretty much like described [here](https://superuser.com/q/1104693/576393), including `netsh wlan show drivers` giving `Hosted Network Supported : No`) and I wonder if it's still possible to create a WiFi connection between the 2 devices. I don't actually care which one becomes a host device, the only things that matter are

- how easily and quickly the WiFi gets up (with AutoHotKey I used to have a key combination which launched `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` so it was button-press-away) and
- it's preferrable to make DHCP give the connecting device the same IP so that the connection in browser is done via the same address each time.

Any ideas how this can be implemented these days?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't nowadays Android phones have feature to become hotspot?

If your phone doesn't, you can try [this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/be.mygod.vpnhotspot/)

Comment: many of them only can become hotspot when they are connected to Internet which is not what I need, but there are third-party apps that seem to help (thanks!): I've installed [Portable Wi-Fi hotspot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.core.technology.wifi.hotspot) and it creates WiFi, but the server isn't accessible via 0.0.0.0:port, only via the IP of the new network, so I'll  ask the devs why is that and can it be changed, I don't want to switch the settings back and forth for each connection/disconnection

Answer (score 1):

Prior to windows including such a function, there were lots of third party software to achieve what you want. Try looking for "hotspot" applications, a quick search in alternativeto gave me this one: http://www.pcfaster.com/en/lp/wifiPopularize.php?from=nav

As bob said, using the phone as a host using native android/ios function is also an option.